# CASE WHEN with four dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have four datetime columns and  I would like an extra string column which shows the value `X` when the most recent date in the row is 5 years older than current date. I'm trying to achieve that with `CASE WHEN` but I'm struggling to make SQL only compare the current date with the most recent date. This is my data:

```
ID | StartDate  | EndDate    | Modified | DoneDate 
1    2013-12-31   2015-03-20   2013-12-31  NULL    
2    2013-06-27   2013-07-24   2013-06-27  NULL            
3    1991-07-11   2001-07-11   2017-10-10  2017-10-10
```

This is the desired result:

```
ID | StartDate  | EndDate    | Modified | DoneDate     | Marked 
1    2013-12-31   2015-03-20   2013-12-31  NULL            NULL
2    2013-06-27   2013-07-24   2013-06-27  NULL             X
3    1991-07-11   2001-07-11   2017-10-10  2017-10-10      NULL
```

Any ideas how to achieve that with case when? I have currently this but it does not look at the most recent date and marks each row with X:

```
,CASE 
 WHEN DATEDIFF(YEAR, Modified, GETDATE()) >= 5 THEN 'X'
 WHEN DATEDIFF(YEAR, EndDate, GETDATE()) >= 5 THEN 'X'
 ELSE ' '
 END as 'Marked'
```

We can assume that `DoneDate` >= `Modified` >= `EndDate` >= `StartDate`.

Comment: _“but I'm struggling to make SQL only compare the current date with the most recent date”_ - what do you mean by “only the current” and “most recent” date here …?

Comment: In the first row of my example, I want SQL to compare the current date with the most recent one which is 2015-03-20. If it's older than 5 years which is not the case, I want to mark it with 'X'.

Comment: So your query would have to figure out which of those four dates - start, end, modified, done - is the most recent one first? You only want your X for that whole row based on that one most recent date?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: Can it be assumed that always DoneDate >= Modified >= EndDate >= StartDate? (So that you would effectively just have to find the first non-NULL one of those in that order, and not determine an _actual_ minimum value first.)

Comment: Yes I think you're right.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [DATE_ADD()](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_date_add.asp)

```
CASE
    WHEN CURRENT_DATE > DATE_ADD(Modified, INTERVAL 1 YEAR) THEN 'X'
    WHEN CURRENT_DATE > DATE_ADD(EndDate, INTERVAL 1 YEAR) THEN 'X'
    ELSE ' '
END AS Marked
```

Edit: The question tag stated MySQL and so this solution works with MySQL. I'm unsure about SQL Server

Comment: Thank you for suggestion, I've tried it but I don't think DATE_ADD works on SQL Server 2012?

Comment: @Donald then you should fix the tags first of all, because right now it says `mysql`

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to write this expression.
I wrapped `DATEDIFF` into `ISNULL` to take into account possible `NULL` values.

```
,CASE WHEN 
    ISNULL(DATEDIFF(YEAR, StartDate, GETDATE()), 999) >= 5 AND
    ISNULL(DATEDIFF(YEAR, EndDate,   GETDATE()), 999) >= 5 AND
    ISNULL(DATEDIFF(YEAR, Modified,  GETDATE()), 999) >= 5 AND
    ISNULL(DATEDIFF(YEAR, DoneDate,  GETDATE()), 999) >= 5
 THEN 'X'
 ELSE ' '
 END AS Marked
```

Answer (score 0):

Following CBroe's comment on the date's possible values, you just need the first non-null value from the following order: DoneDate, ModifiedDate, StartDate, EndDate.

```
CASE 
    WHEN DATEDIFF(
        YEAR,
        COALESCE(DoneDate, ModifiedDate, StartDate, EndDate),
        GETDATE()) >= 5 THEN 'X'
    ELSE ' ' END AS 'Marked'
```